# Why are there still developed countries with low cigarette prices?

Tags: healthcare

The negative effects of smoking are long proven and nearly every country in the world has committed to fight the practice. It is also well known what causes people to quit smoking - high prices, restrictions on public smoking, disgusting and plain packaging, etc. However even within the EU the fight against smoking seems to be highly inconsistent - many countries still have relatively cheap cigarettes and few have implemented extreme packaging laws.

So what's the holdup? Why don't all developed countries simultaneously pass a set of restrictions on smoking, using the best practices in the area?

Comment: https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/indusclient.php?id=A02 One word: "Lobbying"

Comment: Why should the bully pulpit of government force be used to persuade free people away from making a free choice on what they do to their body? Separately, do high prices cause people to quite smoking, or do high prices create an incentive for a black market?

Comment: You do understand different countries are different right? Generally it is easier for a nation to do something than to get their neighbors to do it the same way.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultivation_of_tobacco#/media/File:TobaccoYield.png

Comment: A beautiful example of game theory. Cigarettes in France are more expensive than in all neighboring countries (except britain, which is not exactly a neighbor). As a result, it is estimated that 1 in 5 to 1 in 4 cigarettes smoked in France was bought in another country  (I contribute to this practice, so I know it well)

Comment: @user5751924 yes it's even more strange within the EU - one can literally pack a van full of cigarettes in Romania and then smoke them for the rest of their life somewhere in Sweden.

Comment: Wrong. Leaving aside that tobacco deteriorates with time, the taxes on tobacco (and alcohol) are mostly **excise duties** and as such `are paid by the consignee in the country of destination` (http://www.europedia.moussis.eu/books/Book_2/5/14/02/03/?all=1). Get into Sweden with a van full of cigarettes and the Swedish officials will present you with a tax bill. And that only if you meet whatever requirements Sweden has for tobacco sellers; as explained above such a quantity must be distributed or most of it will go to waste.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am not sure whether you *can* but you definitely *may not*. Tobacco, alcohol (and also “means of transportations” and a bunch of other things) are explicitly excluded from the EU freedom of movement rules. The limits are higher than when coming from outside the EU (especially for alcohol) but not meaningless. For contiguous countries within the Schengen area, they are also somewhat more difficult to enforce but between Romania and Hungary, you do have to stop at the border (for another purpose, admittedly) and I would expect border guards to take notice.

Comment: @Relaxed there are no strict limits, you just have to prove the products are for your personal use and not for resale: https://www.gov.uk/duty-free-goods/arrivals-from-eu-countries. If I were a Swedish smoker I'd definitely be on a plane to Romania every year. Same with alcohol, but that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Related: [Why haven't any Governments banned cigarette sales when it has been proven that it's harmful?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/why-havent-any-governments-banned-cigarette-sales-when-it-has-been-proven-that/)

Comment: @JonathanReez That's technically true but is still very different from regular rules and I am pretty sure a van would not pass muster (while it correctly states that the quantities quoted are guidelines rather than hard limits, that's also what the page you linked to implies).

Comment: It might help if you (1) define what you believe to be a "low" cigarette price; and (2) list some examples of developed countries with such low prices. In many developing countries you can get a cigarette for a few US cents. But off the top of my head I can't really think of any developed country where this is anywhere near the case.

Comment: @KennyLJ good point. I took [Numbeo's](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/prices_by_country.jsp?displayCurrency=USD&itemId=17&regionCode=150) data on cigarette prices and salaries. Out of developed countries, the most expensive cigarettes relative to median income are in New Zealand, where one can buy less than 150 packs per month. In Belgium you can buy 300 packs per month, 450 packs in the US, 600 packs in Japan and 1200 in the UAE. As you can see the approach is not fully consistent.

Comment: @KennyLJ the packaging approach is even less consistent - few countries use the latest techniques, such as the ban on using a unique design and the requirement to put graphic images on each package.

Comment: OK... so what are some developed countries that (in your opinion) have low cigarette prices? And what are the prices there?

Comment: @KennyLJ UAE and Qatar are extremely cheap (less than 3 dollars per pack). Japan is cheap too (4 dollars per pack). Switzerland is cheap for its salaries (8 dollars per pack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly a bunch of factors that play a role, here are two that haven't been mentioned so far (I think):

- The rule making process is long and complicated. For example, smoking bans in bars, restaurant or public transportation are now very common in the EU. The details vary but I think there is some type of ban in just about any EU country and you can clearly see a trend from the year 2000s onwards. But it didn't happen all at once, this rules need to be established country-by-country and sometimes even province-by-province.
- The cost of living (and income) vary widely. To continue with an example you mentioned in the comments, Romania is one of the poorest country in the EU, its GDP per capita is a fourth of that of Germany, a fifth of that of Denmark and half that of the Czech Republic. There is just no way the price of a pack of cigarettes could realistically be set at (the equivalent of) €6 over there.

  That's one example of a larger issue with the last waves of enlargement. When countries like Greece or Portugal joined, they were relatively poor but not *that* poor that the imbalance would create serious tensions and also small enough that larger, richer countries could ignore the problem and wait for convergence. Everything (free movement for services, goods, and people, borderless travel) becomes much more of an issue when the gap is bigger.

Comment: I took [Numbeo's](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/prices_by_country.jsp?displayCurrency=USD&itemId=17&regionCode=150) data on cigarette prices and salaries. Out of EEA countries, the most expensive cigarettes (relative to median income after tax) are in Hungary of all places where one can only afford 140 packs per month. And the cheapest cigarettes are in Switzerland where the average smoker can get 600 packs per month.

Answer (score 3):

Three factors are playing a part of this problem:

1. The lobbyism in the tobacco industry is one of the biggest and strongest in the world.
2. The tobacco industry is expanding in countries with a large working class because the less educated a profession is, the more keep people in this profession is to smoke*. This means that even though the number of smokers are falling in the western world, globally the numbers are increasing**. They are expanding in pretty developed countries because the marked is present.
3. The tobacco industry have for very long disproved, by using statical math and taking advance of doubt, the link between smoking and cancer. A large portion of the tobacco profit is spent on creating "safer" cigarrets, less smelly cigaretes and sow on. ***

*sorry, I only have a danish source: https://www.avisen.dk/joachim-b-ufaglaerte-er-ikke-mere-nedslidte-end-aka_434090.aspx

**John Oliver: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UsHHOCH4q8

** This is from a source.

Answer (score 0):

Smoke cannot be banned because it would be a huge and totally unrequested and unacceptable limitation of people freedom. Smoking a lot is as dangerous as many other "a lot" things in our life, for example:

> "the negative effects of eating junk food are long proven"

but have you ever heard of a government trying to impose its population an healthy diet? How do you think people would react? Another example, many motorcyclists die every year because, let's be honest, it's a dangerous hobby (I'm a motorcyclist myself and aware of it)

What a government can do is to educate people and try to limit collateral damage (aka passive smoke, in this case)

What a government cannot do is to just step up and say "ok, from now on we'll tax tobacco so that no one will be able to buy it", because it would be exactly like banning it. And by the way, you are asking why governments do not raise prices of cigarettes, but cigarettes are a just a normal products from some manufacturer; the government cannot just impose price of products to companies (again, freedom). Up to a limit you can justify higher taxis to cover national health expenditure (in case of cigarettes, it's different for other taxis), but to raise prices to the level of making them impossible to buy? Naaa.

---

And, note: I lost my loved grandfather 'cause of smoking, I don't like smoke at all (not just for my grandfather), I'm happy that I don't have to passively smoke when drinking my coffee, and so on. Still, I think we should stop being hypocrites when it comes to it; people have the right to choose, everybody is informed about the risk of smoke, we don't even allow advertising on cigarettes, it's more than enough; once you spread information, once you educate people, once you've done everything possible, heck, let people take their decisions. It's their life, after all, and unlike drugs they are only damaging themselves.

Could I take a decision, I'd remove the idiotic law about the ugly packages and about sponsorships.

Comment: That's not answering the question.

Comment: @JonathanReez It is "Why don't all developed countries simultaneously pass a set of restrictions on smoking, using the best practices in the area?". Every country is doing its best to cope up with its citizens needs and priorities; what you feel are cheap cigarettes more probably are cigarettes taxed at the maximum that it's acceptable, and so on.

Comment: @JonathanReez totally unrelated: can you please post your Rome2Rio comment to my question on Travel.Se, as an answer instead? It's the only correct answer, I hate seeing it lingering in the comments.

Comment: Your comment does answer the question. However the answer itself is more of an explanation of libertarian values. I fully agree however I think it's hypocritical to allow cigarettes because of 'freedom' and ban drugs because 'they're bad'.

Comment: Which question? Post a link and I will

Comment: @JonathanReez 
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93568/ferries-route-planner